# Split number and percent sign for comparison

Tags: perl

I have written a small perl script to detect, if a partition has problems due to fillup.

I call my script by bash shell like this:

```
chk_part.sh /PARTITION
```

It works well, but i have problems with counters beginning with 8 or 9.
e.g. if my partition has 8% filled up i get "critical"

I think the problem is that I'm using character (`%`) and digit (8) mixed up for my comparisons (`lt`, `gt`, `eq`).

How can I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(switch say);

my $LZE = shift(@ARGV);

# die "Usage: $0 Partition\n" if @ARGV < 1;

my $used_space = `df -h $LZE |awk 'FNR == 2 {print \$5}'`;

given ($used_space) {
    chomp($used_space);
    when ($used_space lt '75%') { print "OK - $used_space of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(0); }
    when ($used_space eq '75%') { print "WARNING - $used_space of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(1);  }
    when ($used_space gt '75%') { print "CRITICAL - $used_space of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(2); }
    default { print "UNKNOWN - $used_space of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(3); }
}
```

Comment: This hasn't anything to do with parsing the output (you have answers already) but I __strongly__ recommend to apply the `-P` switch to `df`, i.e. `df -hP`. Else you may get the output of `df` split up in _two_ lines if the filesystem's name is too long. [See here](http://askubuntu.com/q/55702/504066) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the `%` sign. A good way to do that is to use a regular expression match and a capture group. At the same time, this helps to find malformed output from `df`.

```
my $res = `df -h $LZE |awk 'FNR == 2 {print \$5}'`;
$res =~ m/(\d+)%/;
my $used_space = $1 or die "Something went wrong with df: $!";

given ($used_space) {
    when ($used_space < 75) { ... }
}
```

The line `my $used_space = $1 or die "Something went wrong with df: $!";` assigns the value of the match (`$1` is the first capture group) to `$user_space`. That operation returns that same value. If it's not a true value (i.e. `undef`), the low-binding `or` will trigger its right-hand-side command, and the program will die.

See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) for more information.

Comment: Just a side note: malformed output of `df` ([like here](http://askubuntu.com/q/55702/504066)) can also be avoided by applying `-P` (`df -hP`).

Answer (score 2):

Note that `given/when` is experimental, you might want to reconsider using it. Either way, I've made some slight changes to make your code do what you want.

It removes the `%` from `$used_space` in a regex search/replace, removed the `%` sign from the actual comaprisons, and added it into the print results.

```
my $used_space = `df -h $LZE |awk 'FNR == 2 {print \$5}'`;

$used_space =~ s/%//;

given ($used_space) {
    chomp($used_space);
    when ($used_space < 75) { print "OK - $used_space% of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(0); }
    when ($used_space == 75) { print "WARNING - $used_space% of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(1);  }
    when ($used_space > 75) { print "CRITICAL - $used_space% of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(2); }
    default { print "UNKNOWN - $used_space% of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(3); }
}
```

Comment: That's still doing stringwise comparisons, so hasn't actually fixed the problem.

Comment: updated, but it does work properly with the string comparison operators (at least on 5.24.0)

Answer (score 2):

Or without the unnecessary forking of 3 external binaries (`bash` + `df` + `awk`) and parsing its output - by using the [Filesys::Df](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::Df) or the [Filesys::DfPortable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::DfPortable) for example as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Filesys::Df;
my $limit = 75;
my @txt = qw(OK WARNING CRITICAL);

for my $fs (@ARGV) {
    my $ref = df($fs);
    unless($ref) { warn "Unknown filesystem $fs"; next }
    my $lev = $ref->{per} < $limit ? 0 : $ref->{per} == $limit ? 1 : 2;
    say "$txt[$lev] - $ref->{per}% of disk space used by $fs";
}
```

using it as `./mydf / /foobar /tmp` prints

```
OK - 66% of disk space used by /
Unknown filesystem /foobar at ./mydf line 10.
OK - 10% of disk space used by /tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `eq` and the like aren't doing what you assume. They're string value comparisons, so are doing alphanumeric comparisons.

See: [`perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators)

You're getting away with it, because alphabetically comparing 'two digit' percentages gets you the right result.

But if you're sorting alphabetically: `ab` comes before `cdefg`.

So basically - don't use those operators. Make a numeric value out of your numbers (`s/%//g`  will do it) and then compare with `==` or `<` or `>`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @values = ( '7%', '8%', '9%', '10%', '11%', '75%', '80%', '100%' );

print join "\n", sort { $a cmp $b } @values;
```

This gives you an order of:

```
10%
100%
11%
7%
75%
8%
80%
9%
```

I'm pretty sure that's almost exactly what you *don't* want. (because '100% full' is less that `75%`!)

Changing the values to lose the percent, then using the numeric operators is the way to go.

```
s/%//g for @values;
print join "\n", sort { $a <=> $b } @values;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point that `awk` is useless here:

```
my $used_space = `df -h $LZE`;
$used_space =~ m/(\d+)%/;
$used_space = $1;

given ($used_space) {
    when ($used_space <  75) { print "OK - $used_space of disk space used by $LZE\n"; exit(0); }
...
```